What is the proper way to comment in a makefile recipe?
For years I have lived with this annoying Emacs behavior:

As described in this question
Today I realized that Emacs is actually right: make is not interpreting those lines as comments. It just passes them to the shell and the shell interprets them as comments. Which means that:

it is up to shell to decide that those are comments
and worse: there is an overhead caused by the comments

What would be the proper way of commenting (with a real makefile comment) within a recipe / target, without visually breaking indentation?

What about configuring Emacs to automatically align comments in recipes with the rest using spaces instead of tabs, and to not highlight them?


What would be the proper way of commenting (with a real makefile comment) within a recipe / target, without visually breaking indentation?

Not really.

Anything you indent with a leading tab is part of the recipe, and will be sent to the shell.  That cannot be a "real makefile comment", as you seem to mean that.

If you indent with zero or more spaces instead of a tab then you can have a real makefile comment, but then you will have a visual break in the indentation under at least some circumstances. This will depend on how many spaces, if any, you use to indent, and how widely your particular editor spaces tab stops. You cannot simultaneously satisfy all possible configurations of all editors in this regard.

Additionally, if you happen to indent with enough spaces to match your particular editor's tab stop spacing, then your editor may present a visual indication, because that's usually an error in a Makefile.  I dunno about emacs, but certainly vim does this.



Thanks. The response seems to be then that "make only supports comments with (optional) leading spaces then. This is a good compromise for me: I always use 8-spaces tab in emacs for makefiles, so that's what I will start using then.

A pitty that make does not support "real target comments" (for lack of a better name), that is, comments in a recipe indented to the level of the recipe (that is what target comments means in my book)

And emacs does not mark the indentation with spaces and a comment as an error. Are you sure that is an error? My make is happy about them ...

@blueFast, indentation with spaces is usually a semantic error, but not necessarily a syntax error. If it's a comment that is indented that way then make should accept it as such. If editors flag it, as vim does, then that's because they suppose that you most likely meant to indent with a tab instead.

You are perfectly allowed to use proper make comments within a recipe. Simply don't indent them, like you already did in one of your examples.
target-annoying-face:
# a comment
    echo "Hi"
# another comment
    echo "Bye"


Absolutely true, but this does not seem to satisfy the OP's objective of avoiding a visual break in indentation.

Thanks, but even worse than a performance hit is an eye-sore hit. The problem is that emacs makes my eyes bleed because of the face it uses to hightlight those "makefile errors". Fortunately this has an easy fix: change the face that make uses for that.
